# Is there a way to call update_or_create and not update a field if it's already populated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I know the logic for Django's `update_or_create` is mostly meant to create a record if a matching record isn't found, so in the instance when `update` is being run, can I avoid updating a particular field if it's already populated?

Basically, I want to update a timestamp field (`first_updated`) to track when the record was first updated. The record would keep on updating other fields, but I want this `first_updated` timestamp field updated once and never again.

Does `update_or_create` allow this logic natively, or what are some ways to do this?

Would I need to check the table to see if this record's `first_updated` is populated and if so, run `update_or_create` without `first_updated`?

Any functions in Django that would make this a bit easier to implement?

Comment: first updated means *created*?

Comment: You can make a field `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`, and simply not mention it in `.update_or_create`.

Comment: Yeah, but I would have to make it into two logical scenarios right? Like `if record exists and first_updated is null: update_or_create with field` and another scenario `else: update_or_create without field`

Comment: no, since the field's default value, specified by `auto_now_add` is only triggered when creating the field. Note that Django implements `get_or_create` itself by retrieving and (optionally) updating. So it is not turned into an SQL statement that does that.